# How can I wire a GFCI combo switch so that the switch controls the receptacle?

Tags: electrical, switch, receptacle

I want to install a Cooper Combination Switch/Receptacle GFCI device. Everything I've seen shows the switch controlling a light or garbage disposal and the outlet always hot. I want the switch to control only the outlet, nothing else. There will be a single 12/2 w/ground wire feeding the box. The purpose is to have a protected outlet to control anything plugged into it and operated by the switch. The plan is to have it placed under the eave on the deck and be able to switch on or off something like Christmas lights or a rope light over the deck. The attached picture is as close as I've seen but I need the light to go away and keep the outlet controlled by the switch.

[image: Diagram]

Diagrams belong to do-it-yourself-help.com originals found here: http://www.do-it-yourself-help.com/gfci-outlet-switch-wiring.html

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the device, it should go something like this.

[image: Combo switch GFCI device wiring]

Wiring the device in this way, should allow the switch to control the receptacle. The switch will also control anything connected to the Load terminals, and the Load terminals will be GFCI protected.

***NOTE:*** For outdoor installations, don't forget the in-use weatherproof cover.

Comment: Thank you Tester101. That is about what I thought it would look like but I have no idea what is going on inside the housing as far as connections and did not want to take a chance. I hope to complete the project later this week. Thanks again.